# ExtJs set RadioGroup Item by model

Tags: extjs, extjs5

i have some problems setting the selected item of a radio button group by my viewmodel. Is it possible to set the selected value by the name of the element? I expected hat the viewmodel gender = true matches the second ('female') radio button.

```
Ext.application({    
    launch: function () {

        var form = Ext.widget('form', {

            renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
            viewModel: {
                data: {
                    gender: true
                }
            },

            items: [{
                xtype: 'radiogroup',
                fieldLabel: 'Gender',
                name: 'rbGender',
                defaults: {
                    flex: 1
                },
                layout: 'hbox',
                items: [{
                    boxLabel: 'Male',
                    name: 'gender',
                    inputValue: false,
                    id: 'radio1'
                }, {
                    boxLabel: 'Female',
                    name: 'gender',
                    inputValue: true,
                    id: 'radio2'
                }]
            }]

        });

    }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this is not possible with viewModel. viewModel always relies on the [`bind`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.1/classic/Ext.mixin.Bindable.html#cfg-bind) configuration, e.g.

bind: '{gender}',

You don't want to bind the radio control, you want to bind the radiogroup. What you also want to do is to set the `radiogroup` to `simpleValue: true`.

Working example:

```
viewModel: {
    data: {
        gender: false
    }
},

items: [{
    xtype: 'radiogroup',
    fieldLabel: 'Gender',
    name: 'rbGender',
    bind: '{gender}', // <- bind this field to the viewModel's "gender" value.
    simpleValue: true, // <- use a boolean, not an object.
    defaults: {
        flex: 1
    },
    ...
```

If you want to do the "old-school" way with `name`, you have to use [`form.setValues()`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.1/classic/Ext.form.Basic.html#method-setValues) and [`form.getValues()`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.1/classic/Ext.form.Basic.html#method-getValues) instead of the viewModel.

In ExtJS 5.x, `simpleValue` is not available and the `defaultBindProperty` is null, so you have to change:

```
viewModel: {
    data: {
        gender: { // In ExtJS 5, radiogroups can only take objects, not simple values
            rbGender: false
        }
    }
},

items: [{
    xtype: 'radiogroup',
    fieldLabel: 'Gender',
    name: 'rbGender',
    bind: { // bind has to be a complex object, because defaultBindProperty is not available.
        value:'{gender}'
    },

    items: [{
        boxLabel: 'Male',
        name: 'rbGender', // <- tell the radiogroup to put the rbGender property into these checkboxes
```

Comment: Thank you for your answere. I tried it the way with binding but somehow it doesn't work: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/29c7

Comment: Two reasons: 1) your ExtJS version does not understand simpleValue: true and has no equivalent and 2) in your ExtJS version, radiogroup's `defaultBindProperty` is not `value`, as in the later versions. I have amended my answer.